# OpenApi generator generates client APIs with placeholder in the path get URISyntaxException

Tags: java, generator, openapi, uribuilder

I am working on a Java Project with Maven, SpringBoot and OpenAPI.
In the pom.xml, we added plugin of openapi-generator-maven-plugin version 5.2.1

In the openapi yaml file we have path like below as an example:
`"api/v1/companies/{companyId}/employees"`

The plugin works and we have the client api (EmployeeApi.java) generated.
But when I use this generated api to call, I got an URISyntaxException. With debug I localed the issue happens on the line of
`UriBuilder uriBuilder = UriBuiler.fromUri(this.apiClient.getBasePath() + "/api/v1/companies/{companyId}/employees");`

And it complains the error is the incorrect character of "{"

I noticed the call of UriBuilder.fromUri() will eventually create the URI object by new URI(str) so it cannot take "{" as a valid path. My question is I have no control of the generated codes, how could we ask the generator to use UriBuilder.fromResource or something else which could make this working?

Thanks

Comment: why do you need to use UriBuilder? The base idea is to get feign or retrofit and just use them.

Comment: Hi @AndreyB.Panfilov, I might not make it clear. The UriBuilder line comes from the auto-generatoed codes from that openapi-generator-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

We decided to use one of "resttemplate", "rest-assure" or "apache-httpclient" instead of google-api